# Standalone DBExpress connection editor (Delphi 2009)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, dbexpress

is there a free standalone editor for DBExpress connections (Delphi 2009) that can be installed on a customer PC and be used to manage DBExpress connections and (if available) drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any available as of today. However, it'd be easy to write one, as it mainly involves the manipulation of several ini files.